# "confirm" in "if". How can "confirm" starts if it's located only inside "if"?

Tags: javascript, function, if-statement, confirm

Here is the code. Could you please explain how the "confirm" works here. It just says, that: "if there is the "confirm" but the is no command "confirm" in fact.

```
function ask(question, yes, no) {
    if (confirm(question)) {
        yes()
    }
    else {
        no();
    }
  }

function showOk() {
  alert( "You are agree." );
}

function showCancel() {
  alert( "You cancelled." );
}

ask("Are you agree?", showOk, showCancel);
```

Comment: I'm guessing this is JavaScript. If not, you can [edit] your question to remove the tag I added.

Comment: And — yes, there is a built-in `confirm` function: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm

Comment: Try googling "JavaScript confirm".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[`confirm`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/confirm) is build-in js function (like lots of [other functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects)) that returns `true`/`false`.

`if (confirm())` - `confirm` will be executed first and only than `if` will compare if this function response is `true` or `false`